# Passing around member functions in C#

Tags: c#

Mostly it comes handy that C# delegates already store the object together with the member function. But is there a way, to store -- and pass as parameters -- only the member function itself, just as the good old pointer-to-member-function in C++?

In case the description is less than clear, I give a self-contained example. And, yes, in the example the insistence to pass around member functions is totally pointless, but I have more serious uses for this.

```
class Foo {
    public int i { get; set; }
    /* Can this be done?
    public static int Apply (Foo obj, ???? method, int j) {
        return obj.method (j);
    }
    */
    public static int ApplyHack (Foo obj, Func<int, int> method, int j) {
        return (int) method.Method.Invoke (obj, new object [] { j });
    }
    public static readonly Foo _ = new Foo (); // dummy object for ApplyHack

    public int Multiply (int j) {
        return i * j;
    }
    public int Add (int j) {
        return i + j;
    }
}
class Program {
    static void Main (string [] args) {
        var foo = new Foo { i = 7 };
        Console.Write ("{0}\n", Foo.ApplyHack (foo, Foo._.Multiply, 5));
        Console.Write ("{0}\n", Foo.ApplyHack (foo, Foo._.Add, 5));
        Console.ReadKey ();
    }
}
```

You see, the only workaround I've found is rather ugly and probably slow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Taking your existing code:

```
public static int ApplyHack (Foo obj, Func<int, int> method, int j) {
    return (int) method.Method.Invoke (obj, new object [] { j });
}
```

You could do something like this:

```
public static int ApplyHack (Foo obj, Func<int, int> method, int j) {
    var func = (Func<int,int>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<int,int>), obj, method.Method);

    return func(j);
}
```

This will create a new delegate around the method and the new object.  To take your first example:

```
public static int Apply (Foo obj, ???? method, int j) {
    return obj.method (j);
}
```

The type you are looking for is `System.Reflection.MethodInfo` and it would look like this:

```
public static int Apply (Foo obj, MethodInfo method, int j) {
    var func = (Func<int,int>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<int,int>), obj, method);

    return func(i);
}
```

Note that while you are allocating delegates for each invocation, I believe this will still be faster than using reflection, since you do not have to box function input/output, nor store it in `object[]` arrays.

Answer (score 10):

What you want is something called an [open instance delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74x8f551.aspx). I've written about them [on my blog](http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/simonc/archive/2010/07/28/93676.aspx)

Basically, you can create a delegate to an instance method without tying it to a particular instance, and specify the instance to use it on when you call it:

```
class Foo {
    public int i { get; set; }

    public int Multiply (int j) {
        return i * j;
    }
    public int Add (int j) {
        return i + j;
    }
}
class Program {
    static void Main (string [] args) {
        Func<Foo, int, int> multiply = (Func<Foo, int, int>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<Foo, int, int>), null, typeof(Foo).GetMethod("Multiply");
        Func<Foo, int, int> add = (Func<Foo, int, int>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<Foo, int, int>), null, typeof(Foo).GetMethod("Add");

        var foo1 = new Foo { i = 7 };
        var foo2 = new Foo { i = 8 };

        Console.Write ("{0}\n", multiply(foo1, 5));
        Console.Write ("{0}\n", add(foo1, 5));
        Console.Write ("{0}\n", multiply(foo2, 5));
        Console.Write ("{0}\n", add(foo2, 5));
        Console.ReadKey ();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're using C# 2.0 or above, and have access to anonymous delegates, you can do it very simply by wrapping the function in an anonymous delegate at the point of storage:

```
class Foo
{
    public Foo(int v)
    {
        this.v = v;
    }
    int v;

    public int Multiply(int x)
    {
        return v * x;
    }

    public int Add(int x)
    {
        return v+x;
    }


    delegate int NewFunctionPointer(Foo, int);
    delegate int OldDelegateStyle(int);

    static void Example()
    {
         Foo f = new Foo(2);
         Foo f2 = new Foo(3);

         // instead of this, which binds an instance
         OldDelegateStyle oldMul = f.Multiply;

         // You have to use this
         NewFunctionPointer mul = delegate(Foo f, int x) { return f.Multiply(x); }
         NewFunctionPointer add = delegate(Foo f, int x) { return f.Add(x); }

         // But can now do this
         mul(f, 4); // = 8
         add(f2, 1); // = 3
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're okay with passing the `this` reference as a parameter, why not just use static methods?

```
class Foo {
    public int i;

    public static int ApplyHack(Foo foo, Func<Foo, int, int> method, int j) {
        return method(foo, j);
    }

    public static int Multiply(Foo foo, int j) {
        return foo.i * j;
    }
}


Console.Write("{0}\n", Foo.ApplyHack(foo, Foo.Multiply, 5));
```

This mainly affects how you construct the `Foo` object, without changing how you use it. It also doesn't prevent you from having a non-static `int Multiply(int)` method.

Comment: Definitely cleaner... however, if you already have the delegate, you don't need the `ApplyHack` method to call it.

Comment: Agreed, but since the question suggests there is more to this problem than shown in the example, I tried to keep my answer similar.

Comment: Note that you can also rename `Multiply` to `operator*` to overload the operator if that is more useful to you.

Answer (score 2):

You could retrieve and reuse the MethodInfo for the method or just use the name and extract the method at runtime.

```
 public static int ApplyHack (Foo obj, string methodName, int j)
 {
    var method = typeof(Foo).GetMethod(methodName);   
    return (int) method.Invoke (obj, new object [] { j });    
 }
```

I'd be very careful that this was actually necessary as it seems like a code smell to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it that way

```
class Foo
{
    public int i { get; set; }

    public static int Apply(Foo obj, Func<int, int, int> method, int j)
    {
        return method(j, obj.i);
    }

    public static int Multiply(int j, int i)
    {
        return i * j;
    }
    public static int Add(int j, int i)
    {
        return i + j;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var foo = new Foo { i = 7 };
    Console.Write("{0}\n", Foo.Apply(foo, Foo.Multiply, 5));
    Console.Write("{0}\n", Foo.Apply(foo, Foo.Add, 5));
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this easily with this if I understand correctly:

```
public static int Apply(Func<int, int> method, int j)
{
    return (int)method.Method.Invoke(method.Target, new object[] { j });
}
```

and call it like this:

```
Console.Write("{0}\n", Foo.Apply(foo.Multiply, 5));
```