# C# method pointer like in C++

Tags: c#, c++, delegates

In C++ I was able to create my method pointer without knowing on which instance it will be called, but in C# I can't do it - I need the instance on the delegate creation.

This is what I'm looking for :

Here is the code from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.action(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Name
{
   private string instanceName;

   public Name(string name)
   {
      this.instanceName = name;
   }

   public void DisplayToConsole()
   {
      Console.WriteLine(this.instanceName);
   }

   public void DisplayToWindow()
   {
      MessageBox.Show(this.instanceName);
   }
}

public class testTestDelegate
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      Name testName = new Name("Koani");
      Action showMethod = testName.DisplayToWindow;
      showMethod();
   }
}
```

But I want to do that :

```
public class testTestDelegate
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Name testName = new Name("Koani");
        Action showMethod = Name.DisplayToWindow;
        testName.showMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to be called an [open instance delegate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188592/passing-around-member-functions-in-c-sharp).

Comment: If you want `testName.showMethod();` syntax that I believe the answer is no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a delegate that takes your instance as a parameter:

```
Name testName = new Name("Koani");
Action<Name> showMethod = name => name.DisplayToWindow();
showMethod(testName);
```

Comment: Oh great that can fill exactly what I needed !